# Scren reader won't read list size / number of <li> elements withinin <ul> or <ol>

Tags: html, list, wai-aria, screen-readers, nvda

I have an unordered list which I want screen readers to read like this: *"XXX_LABEL list with 4 elements"*.

This did work on a different part in the code with <ul> and then followed by DIVs containing <a> tags.

Now I'm further down in this form and there ist a <ul> tag with several <li> tags within that list.
In each <li> tag, there are several <div>-tags and one <input> field.

Right now, when an user tabs an input field, the label of the <ul> will be read, but without the number of elements. So it sounds like this right now: *"XXX_LABEL2 list"*.

What am I doing wrong here?

Sceen reader used: NVDA

Code sample (from browser console in HTML):

```
<ul id="SOMETHING_ID1_LIST" class=textRowListHeader" aria-labelledby="XXX_LABEL2">
  <li class ="textRowListItem">...\</li>
  <li class ="textRowListItem">...\</li>
  <li class ="textRowListItem">...\</li>
  <li class ="textRowListItem">...\</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, interesting.  Looks like a bug in NVDA.  JAWS handles it correctly and says "list with 3 items" in both scenarios.  VoiceOver on iOS handles it partially.  It's something to do with the `<input>` in your second list.  The first list with links works fine.

With VoiceOver, the first list announces "list start" (it doesn't say the number of items but that's a VoiceOver choice) before the first link and then announces "list end" when I get to the last link in the list.  With the `<input>` example, VoiceOver does **not** announce "list start" but **does** announce "list end", so it partially handles it.

Here's the code I used to test with:

```
<button>foo</button>
<ul>
    <li>
        <div>
            <a href='.'>a</a>
            <a href='.'>b</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <a href='.'>c</a>
            <a href='.'>d</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <a href='.'>e</a>
            <a href='.'>f</a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
<button>foo</button>
<ul>
    <li>
        <div>
            <label>a<input></label>
            <label>b<input></label>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <label>c<input></label>
            <label>d<input></label>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <label>e<input></label>
            <label>f<input></label>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
<button>foo</button>
```

(I have dummy buttons before, between, and after the lists so that I have an element to focus on before going into the list.)

The accessibility inspector in Chrome dev tools shows the same properties for both lists so they *should* be announced the same, but that's not what I'm hearing.

You could certainly try to code around it but I wouldn't worry about it.  Instead, you should report a bug to NVDA, https://github.com/nvaccess/nvda/issues